# How to print TEXT_PLAIN format http response received data on iphone simulator using Xcode 4?

Tags: java, objective-c, xcode, tomcat, ios-simulator

I am communicating with Apache server via iphone simulator. When I am sending request from my simulator, apache server is sucessfully responding. I checked via installing wireshark on mac(client), but I am unable to print response value in xcode console or in iphone simulator.

my Response Reciving Code on client side-:

```
// CHECKING CONNECTION ONE


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

    _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"%s checking data ...",_responseData.superclass);
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [_responseData appendData:data];

    NSLog(@"Apended Data.. %d.........%s",data,data);

}

-(NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connectiOn willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse
{
    return nil;

}
```

my request responding code SERVER Side (JAVA) -:

```
@GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
      System.out.println("Request Received Inside text plain method");

      String ram = "Hello Jersey";
    return ram;
  }
```

On client side (iphone simulator) i am receiving rseponse in http text plain format, Please suggest me how to print response value sucessfully. I am getting " ??  " in my response.

Comment: have check in connectionDidFinishLoading what response u r getting

Comment: sir, it was printing data received sucessfully